# Most browser-like convenience password manager

Tags: password-manager

Chrome password manager is super convenient - it autofills passwords on website automatically, has a one-click password generation. However the management of passwords is rather lackluster, there is no fine grained control on how to read passwords, it is cumbersome to use non-browser passwords. An, of course, very often does not recognise there is a password to be filled in. You can usually go around this by manually adding it, but it is rather inconvenient then.

All the password managers I have found, reasearched and used fall short on the convenience. Usually there is at least one more click to fill in the password, creating new account takes often a few more steps (but usually isn't less convenient then websites not recognised by Chrome, sometimes slightly easier).

I am looking for the best out there from UX perspective. I imagine going to a website and the login fields being automatucally pre-filled, as with chrome, a right click "create new account" that behaves the way I configure it (i.e. email with plus, password of specific length and characters group). It would be sweet if it would somehow help with managing SSH. I am not security savy, but if I understand correctly it is not a good practice to store SSH keys, but I would like to be able to have a backup of keys in case I forget to do it manually when changing computer etc. It would be a nice to have, you can comment on why not to or how to do it better.

Please keep the answers close to the question, that is what is the password manager that has the least amount of user interactions to fill in passwords for known website and for creating a new account.

Comment: So, leading password managers like Lastpass, 1Password, Dashlane, and Bitwarden don't pass your convenience check? If not, can you explain why, so that similar solutions don't get recommended? Those top password managers auto-fill passwords and add new accounts with a single click on a pop-up.

Comment: Maybe they do and I do not know how to use them. With Bitwarden to auto create a new account with password and get it saved one has to, on a login page, open extension icon, click plus, select generate password, select generate login, select save, then click on the selected account to get it autofilled. Context menu allows password generation, you can copy it, but then it doesn't get saved. Is there a better way to do it? If not, then I do not understand how you can compare it to a browser right click and generate password.

Comment: In order to fill in password, on chrome you select a field and choose account or if you have just one it autofills without your action. In Bitwarden you click on extension icon and on the account, that's 2 clicks, each of those away from the website and input controls.

Comment: Because when you actually use Bitwarden, for instance, and you log into a new site, it provides a pop-up offering to save the new site. When you re-visit the site, you just click the Bitwarden icon to auto-fill or configure the Bitwarden entry for that site to autofill for you. And, that is the *standard* behaviour for all *four* of the software I provided.

Comment: While I may be using Bitwarden inefficiently (and may have tried out some other password managers in a wrong way), it does fall short on the convenient, as elaborately described in my post and comments. In Bitwarden chrome extension on a new website the easiest way I see is to open extension popup -> add new login -> manually choose username and password (2 clicks each) -> save -> click created account for auto fill. So no, it is not the same as one-click autofills chrome offers (if it recognises website inputs correctly).

Comment: Chrome has fewer clicks than what I have used so far. I am looking for password managers with as little clicks as Chrome. Or a way to use i.e. Bitwarden in a better manner. I.e. I get no Bitwarden popup on a new website.

Comment: @theadam, Chrome also doesn't have a pop-up for a new website to add site before actually signing in, I'm fact you can't Add Site without going to settings. Once you login both Chrome and Bitwarden pop-up with an option to save the site (with the details you just logged in with.)

Comment: In Chrome, if it recognises password, it offers password generations on one click. You can one-click autofill your e-mail too. And then it remembers that immediately. With Bitwarden the steps are listed above - way too much overhead.

Comment: @theadam I flagged your 2nd to last reply because it's the only rude comment under the question. Anyways, Bitwarden has form detection and autofill that you can set in options. And adding new passwords is done with a button click at the top of the page. Ir's not perfect, but you'll waste more time waiting for a perfect as quick as possible solution than if you e.g. wrote a feature request for one of the most known managers to make parts of their process faster.

Comment: Thanks for flagging, I removed the unkind part. theadam, what operating systems and web browsers do you need it to be compatible with?